# Adding image size (dimension) to name of the image when saving

Tags: image, rename, dimensions

I just can't find any answer to this. I have to do this because of my university project. (Stupid...). When you download some image from webpage, you save the image with the name which is on server. But I have to add "x" and "y" sizes to the name of the image.

Any solution? It can be php or jQuery (or maybe just HTML? I don't think so). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try the command on PHP to get image properties

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("img/flag.jpg");
```

and then rename it.

```
rename("img/flag.jpg", substr(filename, 0, -4).$width.$height.substr(filename, -4);)
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to rename images, but how can I call this script on download? I don't want to rename images on server.